# and/or on a where_exp expression on Jekyll

Tags: filter, operators, jekyll

I'm trying to use `where_exp` to filter Jekyll pages based on two categories using `or` operator:

```
{% assign sortedPages = site.pages | sort:"date" | reverse | where_exp:"page","page.categories contains 'design-pattern'" %}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Expected end_of_string but found pipe

Ar `or`/`and` operators really supported? I can't figure out how to filter pages using `where_exp` as shown in my code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue with some workarounds... It's not a very elegant solution, but as Jekyll isn't about creating actual software architecture... For now, it works flawlessly:

```
{% assign patterns = "" | split,"" %}

{% for page in site.pages %}
{% if page.categories contains "design-pattern" or page.categories contains "anti-pattern" %}
{% assign patterns = patterns | push:page %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign sortedPages = patterns | sort:"date" | reverse %}
```

1. I create an empty array.
2. I loop over all pages and I filter them by two possible categories.
3. I push pages that fulfill the whole condition.
4. Once I get the filtered page array, I sort and reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to replicate the error message you included with your original question. However, as far as *filtering based on multiple conditions* goes, **it is supported**. You can also put all of your filters together. The result is much cleaner code

## Example

If one wants to set a variable named "sortedPages" equal to "site.pages", but with the following filters:

- Sort by date
- Sort in reverse order
- Only include a page if it has **design-pattern** and/or **anti-pattern** as a category

they can do so with the following one-liner:

```
{% assign sortedPages = site.pages | sort:"date" | reverse | where_exp: "item", "item.categories contains 'design-pattern' or item.categories contains 'anti-pattern'" %}
```

### Answer as multiple lines

Splitting up statements across multiple lines is also supported. Doing so can sometimes improve readability:

```
{% 
    assign sortedPages = site.pages 
    | sort:"date" 
    | reverse 
    | where_exp: "item", "item.categories contains 'design-pattern' or item.categories contains 'anti-pattern'" 
%}
```

Comment: One thing to note though. The `and` `or` operators in `where_exp` only works from Jekyll 4.0 and above.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to filter posts that don't contain a particular category? Something like `not contains`.

Comment: About `and` with `where_exp` in Jekyll 3.9: you can chain multiple `where_exp` filters in a row. Simulating `or` is more complicated, though. You could assign the two conditions to two separate arrays, concatenate them, then apply the uniq filter... unfortunately, concat requires 4.0+ as well. But you can simulate concat using `join: "|"` on each, then `append`, then `split: '|'`, assuming `|` doesn't appear in your array elements.