# How to use 'where' filters with an 'or' operator

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a Liquid template where I look for documents within a collection where a given metadata tag is "valueA" OR "valueB".

I've tried the following:

```
{% assign item = site.rn | where: "type", "typeA" OR "typeB" %}
```

```
{% assign item = site.rn | where: "type", "typeA" "typeB" %}
```

```
{% assign item = site.rn | where: "type", "typeA" | where: "type", "typeB" %}
```

None of the above examples are returning both items where type=typeA AND items where type=typeB. The first two return only items where type=typeA. The third does not return anything because there are no items where type=typeA and type=typeB.

Comment: [Related stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722902/and-or-on-a-where-exp-expression-on-jekyll)

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

It seems that [binary operator in `where_exp`will not be supported before Jekyll 4](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6998).

As you've pointed in your comment under your question you can loop over your collection and feed an array depending on a if control structure.

```
{% assign items = "" | split:"" %}

{% for item in site.rn %}
  {% if item.type == 'typeA' or item.type == 'typeB' %}
    {% assign items = items | push: item %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### end edit

#### This will work in Jekyll 4

You can try the jekyll specific `where_exp' liquid filter ([see documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)).

```
{% assign item = site.rn | where: "item", "item.type == 'typeA' or item.type == 'typeB'" %}
```

Comment: It seems that "OR" is not supported, and neither are parentheses. It returns errors: "Expected dotdot but found comparison" // "Expected end_of_string but found id"